# Terraform ignore_changes for resource output

Tags: terraform

Is there anyway to ignore changes to resource output? Or tell terraform to not refresh it?

A terraform resource I'm using returns a `state_info` output (map of string) that can be modified by processes outside of Terraform. I want to ignore these changes. Is this possible.

```
resource "aiven_vpc_peering_connection" "this" {

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      state_info
    ]
  }
}
```

`state_info` is getting set to `null` outside of Terraform. I'm using `state_info` in other terraform resources. It's failing with `aiven_vpc_peering_connection.this.state_info is empty map of string` on subsequent terraform plans I run

Comment: That output would be garbage collected by Terraform at the end of its process. How are other non-interacting processes able to modify it?

Comment: it looks like under the hood it's coming from a REST API.

Comment: Does the error only occur when aiven_vpc_peering_connection.this.state_info is referenced in the other resources, or does it occur even if the only reference is in the ignore block you've posted? If the former, then perhaps wrapping the other references in a Try function would let you handle the null? If the latter, then I would think the Aiven provider needs to be fixed to handle the null value.

Comment: Is there any data provider available for `aiven_vpc_peering_connection`? If yes, you could verify the `state_info` and if it's not null, then you could decide to create the resource or not..

Answer (score 1):

The `ignore_changes` mechanism instructs Terraform to disregard a particular argument when it's comparing values in the configuration with values in the prior state snapshot, so it doesn't have any effect for attributes that are *only* saved in the prior state due to them not being explicitly configurable.

It sounds like what you want is instead to have Terraform disregard a particular argument when it's updating the prior state to match remote objects (the "refresh" step), so that the result would end up being a mixture of new content from the remote API and content previously saved in the state. Terraform has no mechanism to achieve that: the values stored in the state after refreshing are exactly what the provider returned. This guarantee can be important for some resource types because retaining an old value for one argument while allowing others to change could make the result inconsistent, if e.g. the same information is presented in multiple different ways.

The closest you can get to what you described is to use the value as exported by the upstream resource and then specify `ignore_changes` on the resource where you ultimately *use* that value, telling Terraform to ignore the changes in the upstream object when comparing the downstream object with its configuration.